# multiple queries for single grid

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have one table as follows>

```
Party_Code | Buy_Sell | Trade_Qty | Market_Rate

 036L09         1         350           20

 036L09         2         300           30
```

I am trying to show one grid in that data as follows>

```
BuyQty | BuyRate | BuyAmt|SellQty | SellRate | SellAmt  

 350       20       7000    300        30        9000
```

For this i have made two queries>>

```
select sum(Trade_qty) as BuyQty, sum(Market_Rate) as BuyAmt from tradeFile where Buy_Sell='1' and Party_Code='036L09'

select sum(Trade_qty) as SellQty, sum(Market_Rate) as SellAmt from tradeFile where Buy_Sell='2' and Party_Code='036L09'
```

I want these queries to be applicable for single grid. For that i written code as>>

```
  try
            {
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("select sum(Trade_qty) as BuyQty, sum(Market_Rate) as BuyAmt from tradeFile where Buy_Sell='1' and Party_Code='0L036'", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                SqlDataAdapter sellDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select sum(Trade_qty) as SellQty, sum(Market_Rate) as SellAmt from tradeFile where Buy_Sell='2' and Party_Code='0L036'", con);
                DataSet dsSell = new DataSet();
                sellDA.Fill(dsSell);

                gv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                gv.DataSource = dsSell.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

But its taking data from last datasource only.

How can i go for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns the result for one specific `Party_Code`

```
select sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Trade_Qty else 0 end) as BuyQty,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Market_Rate else 0 end) as BuyRate,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Trade_Qty*Market_Rate else 0 end) as BuyAmount,

       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Trade_Qty else 0 end) as SellQty,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Market_Rate else 0 end) as SellRate,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Trade_Qty*Market_Rate else 0 end) as SellAmount
from tradeFile
where Party_Code='0L036'
```

and this one returns the result for all Party_Codes

```
select Party_Code,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Trade_Qty else 0 end) as BuyQty,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Market_Rate else 0 end) as BuyRate,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Trade_Qty*Market_Rate else 0 end) as BuyAmount,

       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Trade_Qty else 0 end) as SellQty,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Market_Rate else 0 end) as SellRate,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Trade_Qty*Market_Rate else 0 end) as SellAmount
from tradeFile
group by Party_Code
```

Comment: lozz..It worked. Thank You. I have given my 28 hours for the query. I had enough reputation i would i upvoted you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it will return your needed result in single query

```
SELECT  
        a.Trade_Qty AS BuyQuant, 
        a.Market_Rate AS BuyRate,
        a.Trade_Qty * a.Market_Rate AS BuyAmt,
        b.Trade_Qty AS SellQuant, 
        b.Market_Rate AS SellRate,
        b.Trade_Qty * b.Market_Rate AS SellAmt
FROM 
        tradeFile a, tradeFile b
WHERE 
        a.Party_Code = b.Party_Code AND
        a.Party_Code = '036L09' AND
        a.Buy_Sell = 1 AND
        b.Buy_Sell = 2;
```

For condition having multiple buy sell by 1 party_code try this query

```
SELECT  
        a.Trade_Qty AS BuyQuant, 
        a.Amt,
        b.Trade_Qty AS SellQuant, 
        b.Amt
FROM 
        (SELECT
               Party_Code 
               sum(Trade_Qty) As 'Trade_Qty',
               sum(Trade_Qty * Market_Rate) As 'Amt'
         FROM tradeFile 
         WHERE Party_Code = '036L09' AND
               Buy_Sell = 1
         GROUP BY Party_Code
        ) a, 
        (SELECT
               Party_Code 
               sum(Trade_Qty) As 'Trade_Qty',
               sum(Trade_Qty * Market_Rate) As 'Amt'
         FROM tradeFile 
         WHERE Party_Code = '036L09' AND
               Buy_Sell = 2
         GROUP BY Party_Code
        )  b
WHERE 
        a.Party_Code = b.Party_Code;
```

Comment: by mistake i mentioned second grid, i have edited my question . There is only one grid.

Comment: You cannot provide 2 data source to one grid. If you want to follow your solution of creating 2 different queries then you have to create a new dataTable which has combined entries from both the dataSources which you are populating from both the queries else you can go with a single query which i have mentioned in the answer. Hope this helps....

Comment: but i think your query is helping me. i am trying on it.

Comment: I was finding for sum(a.Trade_Qty),sum(a.Market_Rate) but its taking the sum of whole table. I want it only for partycode=0L036

Comment: I have added the condition `a.Party_Code = '036L09'` add according for the party you want.

Comment: yeah i have also written query like that, but its not considering the a.Party_Code = '036L09' condition

Comment: Its giving me sum for all party codes while i want it only for 036L09 which we have mentioned in where condition

Answer (score 0):

use Group By query like below, this will give you result in the single dataset.

```
select sum(Trade_qty) as Qty, sum(Market_Rate) as Amt, (case when Buy_Sell = 1 then 'Buy' Else 'Sale' end)  as TransactionType from tradeFile where  Party_Code='036L09'
group by Buy_Sell
```

Answer (score 0):

lets try this query :)

```
Select sum(t1.Trade_qty) as BuyQty, sum(t1.Market_Rate) as BuyAmt,
sum(t2.Trade_qty) as SellQty, sum(t2.Market_Rate) as SellAmt FROM tradeFile
INNER join tradeFile t2
ON t1.Party_Code=t2.Party_Code and t1.Buy_Sell='1' and t1.Party_Code='036L09' 
and t2.Buy_Sell='2'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the first place, your query is tottaly wrong like what you said.

```
select sum(Trade_qty) as BuyQty, sum(Market_Rate) as BuyAmt from tradeFile where Buy_Sell='1' and Party_Code='036L09'

select sum(Trade_qty) as SellQty, sum(Market_Rate) as SellAmt from tradeFile where Buy_Sell='2' and Party_Code='036L09'
```

Try this queries

```
SELECT sum(a.Trade_qty) as BuyQty, a.Market_rate as BuyRate, a.Market_rate * sum(a.Trade_qty) as BuyAmt,
       sum(b.Trade_qty) as SellQty, b.Market_rate as SellRate,  b.Market_rate * sum(b.Trade_qty) as SellAmt
FROM tradeFile a
INNER JOIN  tradeFile b on b.id= a.id
GROUP BY a.Market_rate,b.Market_rate
WHERE (a.Buy_Sell ='1' and a.Party_Code='036L09') or (b.Buy_Sell='2'' and.Party_Code='036L09')
```

But this is still generic, you need to make two table, 1 table for sell and 1 table for buy so can join that two table.

about your datasource, it was wrong , you overided the

```
gv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

into

```
gv.DataSource = dsSell.Tables[0];
```

that's why the last queries display.